# QuestDB: Last inserted row using PostgreSQL protocol does not show up in results from SELECT query until a new record is inserted

Tags: questdb

I am new to QuestDB and after reading the docs decided it would be a good fit for an embedded database. The use case for now is to store time-based events originating from network attached IoT devices. Here is the very simple table to store the event data:

```
CREATE TABLE events_7d322320_b503_4b6c_aef1_8d11d55f3778(
ts TIMESTAMP, evtype symbol, evsource symbol, event string)
timestamp(ts)
PARTITION BY DAY;
```

The table name is derived from the IoT device's UUID. Python code using the psycopg module is performing the inserts like this:

```
    try:
        conn = psycopg.connect(qdConnectStr)
    except:
        print("ERROR: Unable to connect to QuestDB service at: {}".format(qdConnectStr))
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(502)
        return

    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO events_{}".format(controllerid.replace('-','_'))  +
                    " (ts, evtype, evsource, event) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                    (timeStamp, evType, evSource, event))
    except:
        print("ERROR: Unable to execute query with QuestDB service.")
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(502)
        return

    else:
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

    cherrypy.response.status = 202
    return
```

And here is an example of the data to be inserted, specifically the string following 'Received':

```
Oct 20 18:00:00 tgrctl events[18669]: Received: 2021-10-20T18:00:00.39070167|STATE::TIMER::ON:lamp1
```

The string is parsed down to match the columns in the table, so that what is actually inserted and retrieved via the SELECT query looks like this:

```
2021-10-20T18:00:00.000000Z | STATE | TIMER | ON:lamp1
```

What is puzzling me is that a record only shows up once a new record is added. Meaning, the above record only appeared in a SELECT query *after* a new row was inserted, say at 22:00:00 the lamp was turned off by a timer.
I have perused all the various configuration parameters, but nothing seems to address this symptom, unless I'm simply missing something.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. If you post fully reproducible example with reading code too as a GitHub bug it would be helpful (https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues)

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was a bug in QuestDB which has since then been fixed, so this question has "expired" in the sense that it cannot be reproduced anymore.